# How to prevent using cache when new data is available?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, core-data

I'm caching data in CoreData within my app to reduce updating request when there's nothing new.

Here's my caching logic in pseudo code:

```
if cacheExistsInCoreData {
  if cacheIsOutdated  {
    loadDataFromRemoteAndCacheItWithCurrentDate()  
  }else {
    useCache()
}else {
  loadDataFromRemoteAndCacheItWithCurrentDate()
}
```

How I check if cache is outdated:

```
func checkIfCacheIsOutdated {
  if lastCachedDate isOrderThan selfDefinedCheckingDate {
   return true // need to load new data
  }else {
   return false // just use cache
  }
}
```

This mechanism works fine almost all the time.

While in rare situation I find my program caches the wrong data with a right date, which means user might see the older data and could not get update when new one is available.

If there's nothing wrong with my caching logic, I wonder if the reason could be that when the remote data is fetched by my app before it gets updated and then gets stored in core data with the latest date time.

A cache in core data includes:

> data(provided by remote server) //nothing I can do with it...
>
> date(provided by me using NSDate())

How can I make sure if the two objects are correctly connected (latest data with current time) before storing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are calling a web api, most of the web apis would return cache headers. It is safe to cache the data based on cache header value, that way there wont be any stale cache.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came across that works for me is to set the stalenessInterval on the Main Queue NSManagedObjectContext as follows inside of your extension:

```
objectContext.stalenessInterval = 0.0;
```

This tells the context in the extension to fetch new data every time and ignore the cache.